# Login with instagram flow breaks when suspicius login is detected

Tags: ios, instagram, instagram-api

We are facing a weird issue to our existing application we have provided login with instagram facility. Please check the flow below.

Normal Flow :

1. User taps on "Login With Instagram"
2. Instagram Login view is presented.
3. User fills out the details and authenticates himself.
4. Instagram Success call back url is called.
5. Mobile app detects the success callback, gets the authentication token.

Flow Where Instagram considers the Login Activity as suspicious:

1. User taps on "Login With Instagram"
2. Instagram Login view is presented.
3. User fills out the details.
4. Instagram thinks of it as suspicious activity and presents him with options to verify using OTP.
5. User completes the OTP challenge.
6. Success callback is never called by Instagram, So our app doesn't know if the user has completed the login process in web view. So user keeps seeing the Instagram feed and never comes back to our app.

We also traced down the URLs in the web view.

Once the application redirects the user to the Instagram login web view the only thing we can capture is the URL redirections that take place in the web view. Whenever suspicious activity is detected and user is presented with the login challenge following redirects are happening.

User presented with login challenge ( OTP )
https://www.instagram.com/challenge/1479194072/4HmLZJYUqo/

Once OTP is verified and it goes directly to https://www.instagram.com/ that results into user's seeing Instagram feed instead of going back to app.

In the normal login flow it redirects to configured URL with #access_token in it.

Please suggest a solution to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 4):

This may happen when same mobile phone is used for login with different accounts. I've also faced this issue. This problem won't occur when we login with single account in a single mobile.

Comment: But as an app developer i cannot control the way users use the mobile app.

Comment: Yes, you are right! But I don't understand why Instagram has this type of security!

Answer (score 1):

After researching our option for the login with Instagram we found that our application was using **Implicit flow** where the access token is being issues in the url itself using some internal redirects.

There is another way to achieve the same flow more secure and recommended by instagram is **Server-side flow**. More details can be found [here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/)